# How to run OfficeJS Excel add-in application only in http based domain without SSL certificate

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

Can you confirm below thing and if so kindly provide samples..

1) Is Office JS Excel add-in works in http based domain without SSL enabled.
2) If so kindly suggest the steps.

Answer (score 1):

Words from official sites:

While not strictly required in all add-in scenarios, using an HTTPS endpoint for your add-in is strongly recommended. Add-ins that are not SSL-secured (HTTPS) generate unsecure content warnings and errors during use. If you plan to run your add-in in Office on the web or publish your add-in to AppSource, it must be SSL-secured. If your add-in accesses external data and services, it should be SSL-secured to protect data in transit. Self-signed certificates can be used for development and testing, so long as the certificate is trusted on the local machine.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/requirements-for-running-office-add-ins

So if you plan to publish the addin, it has to be SSL based.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Also is there any possibility to test sample hosted add-in like LIVE environment with in organization without SSL using node js server?